# Time difference between two columns - mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to do 2 separate queries and need the result.
one is where i need the difference between values of 2 columns in 2 different tables.

```
table 1
user id | userroomid | roomid | createdOn
2           22          54       2018-07-13 03:58:33
3           23          55       2018-07-13 04:58:33
4           26          59       2018-08-13 04:58:33


table 2
user id | roomname | roomid | createdTime
2           asd          54       2018-07-13 03:58:33
3          deg         55       2018-07-13 04:58:33
4           bfds          59       2018-08-13 04:58:33
```

so, I want the time difference between the column createdTime and createdOn from the 2 tables.

and I have already written the other query which is to insert items into a table, but I am not sure how to join these 2 queries and make them one.

here's the 2nd query

```
 let sqlInsert = mysql.format(`INSERT INTO userroom (roomid,userid) VALUES (?, ? )`,[roomid,userid]);
```

So, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: expected output should be time in seconds

Comment: OK, but what does this diff have to do with your insert?  You aren't inserting the difference.

Answer (score 1):

join between that two tables then use `TIMEDIFF` function which  expressed as a time value and TIME_TO_SEC it will convert time in second

Example of TIMEDIFF` function

```
   SELECT TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF('2009-05-18 15:45:57.005678','2009-05-18 13:40:50.005670'));
```

it will return 7507 sec

For your case

```
select TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(t1.createdOn,t2.createdOn)) as time_diff from table1 t1 
inner join  table2 t2 on  t1.user id=t2.user id
```